# Javascript Calculator double digits

Tags: javascript, calculator

I am trying to make a calculator that is simple. However I am having a problem when trying to add, subtract, multiply and divide a double digit number. So far when I plug in a 3 it lets me but if I press 3 again it will just show another 3 instead of making it 33. How do I fix my Javascript in order to be able to compute double digit numbers (or even more). so far this is what I have for this particular problem

```
var firstNumber;
var secondNumber;
var clear;
var operation;

function calculate() {
        var answer;
        if (operation == "+") {
        answer = firstNumber + secondNumber;
        } else if (operation == "-") {
            answer = firstNumber - secondNumber;
        } else if (operation == "*") {
            answer = firstNumber * secondNumber;
        }else if (operation == "/") {
            answer = firstNumber / secondNumber;
        }
       firstNumber = answer; 
        displayAnswer(answer)
        }
       }


function DisplayOutput(data) {
    var display = firstNumber + " " + operation + " " + secondNumber;
    document.getElementById('answer').textContent = data; 
}

function SaveNumber(number) {
    if (firstNumber == undefined) {
        firstNumber  = number;
    }else if (firstNumber != undefined) {
        secondNumber = number;
    }
    DisplayOutput(number); 
}

function Operation(op){
    operation = op;
    DisplayOutput(op);
}

function displayAnswer(answer){
    document.getElementById('answer').textContent=answer;
}

function clearData(){
   firstNumber = null;
   secondNumber = null;
   answer = 0;
   DisplayOutput(answer);
}
```

Comment: Please post a complete code example. And a jsFiddle.net example would be helpful too.

Comment: I have added my full js file

Answer (score 0):

I'll try and explain what Paul Hagerty did with his calculator on stanford's objective-c course.

Add a variable that keeps track of when the user is pressing digits.

For example...

```
var userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping = false;
```

when the user presses a digit, this var changes it's value to true, and you concatenate the new digit with the ones you already had. When the user enters a new number you check this var, if it's true then you concatenate again.

When the user presses an operand (+, -, x, etc) reset the var's value to false, so it knows the user finished entering the number and the next number he inputs is a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I believe when you enter a number, you use the function SaveNumber.

First of all, you don't need the if after the else, the else already is a "if (firstNumber != undefined)".

Second, if you place the first 3, the firstNumber becomes defined, therefore you are changing the secondNumber.
What you need to do is to change to the secondNumber only when a operator is inserted.
For that, you can create an auxiliary variable.

Third, how are you adding the digits?

```
var isFirstNumber = true;
```

...

```
function SaveNumber(number) {
    if (isFirstNumber) {
        firstNumber = firstNumber*10; // This shifts the inserted digits to the left
        firstNumber = firstNumber + number;
    } else {
        secondNumber = secondNumber*10;
        secondNumber = secondNumber + number;
    }
    DisplayOutput(number); 
}
```

And where you process the input, when you get an operator you should do:

```
isFirstNumber = false;
```